# How to make this loop more functional without bringing too much overheads

Tags: f#

```
 for i in a..b do
     res <- res * myarray.[i]
 res
```

Do I have to use like

```
  Array.fold (*) 1 (Array.sub myarray a (b - a + 1))
```

, which I believe is rather slow and not that concise?

Comment: I would say the biggest problem is a redundant mutable variable which is easy to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel's solution is pretty neat and I think it should be nearly as efficient as the `for` loop, because it does not need to clone the array.

If you wanted a more concise solution, then you can use indexer instead of `Array.sub`, which does need to clone some part of the array, but it looks quite neat:

```
myarray.[a .. b] |> Seq.fold (*) 1
```

This clones a part of the array because the slicing operation returns an array. You could define your own slicing operation that returns the elements as `seq<'T>` (and thus does not clone the whole array):

```
module Array =
  let slice a b (arr:'T[]) = 
    seq { for i in a .. b -> arr.[i] }
```

Using this function, you could write:

```
myarray |> Array.slice a b |> Seq.fold (*) 1
```

I believe this more directly expresses the functionality that you're trying to implement. As always with performance - you should measure the performance to see if you need to make such optimizations or if the first version is fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: use ur first method, what can i do if the array is of int[], but the result i want is int64 (multipliaton would generate big integer than int32) DO i have to do fun a b -> a*(int64)b? would the explicit casting on each element cause much overhead?

Comment: @colinfang: No, there is almost no overhead with `int64` function.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if you'll find it any better, but you could do:

```ml
Seq.fold (fun r i -> r * myarray.[i]) 1 {a .. b}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're concerned with speed then I'd shy away from using seq unless you're prototyping.  Either stick with the for loop or rewrite as a recursive function.  The example you gave is simplistic and sometimes more complex problems are better represented as recursion.

```
let rec rangeProduct a b total (array : _[]) =
    if a <= b then
        rangeProduct (a + 1) b (total * array.[a]) array
    else
        total

let res = myArray |> rangeProduct a b res
```

There is no overhead here, it's as fast as possible, there is no mutation, and it's functional.

Comment: You need type annotation for `array`; otherwise the function doesn't type-check.

Comment: @pad my F# fu isn't as good as Brian's yet.  I guess I still have to check if my code compiles.

Comment: You can avoid having type annotations - just give a hint to the typechecker by replacing indexer with Array.get :)